# Can we disable the "Record payment" button on contributions?

Tags: accounting, partial-payments

I've finally just now noticed the ability to record multiple separate payments on contributions in the back-office area, using the "record payment" button.

I didn't realize it, but according to https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/release-notes/4.7.16.md#features this has been around since version 4.7.16.

This is causing a couple of problems for some of my sites:

1. After we enter a partial payment against a contribution, there's no easy facility to find that payment (edit: I mean search for that payment, not just see it within the contribution record). I can search for contributions, but not payments.
2. A couple of my client's custom features weren't anticipating multiple payments, and so aren't correctly reflecting the payments they're entering against contributions.
3. I can't find much documentation about this online.

The above-referenced release notes indicate this was added as part of an effort to support accrual-based accounting. If that's so, is there perhaps a way to disable this functionality, and/or disable other accrual-accounting-related features?

Comment: The "Find Payments" extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/find-payments) claims to support searching for payments.

Answer (score 2):

Once can find payments for contribution by clicking on Amount from Contribution result. The section which appears after clicking on amount shows all the payments against the contribution.
[image]

I believe its not possible to turn off 'Record Payment' link from contribution through UI. But you can implement hook_links() in your extension and unset the record payment link. Here is the snippet on how you can remove the 'record payment link

```
function extension_civicrm_links($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$links, &$mask, &$values) {
  if ($objectName == 'Contribution' && 'contribution.selector.row' == $op) {
    foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
      if ($link['name'] == 'Record Payment') {
        unset($links[$key]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By default Accrual Accounting is disabled until you enable (Enable Deferred Revenue) them by navigating to Administer >> CiviContribute >> CiviContribute Component Setting. You can turn off the settings if its enabled in your site.

HTH

Pradeep